# Django ModelForm Custom Date Field

Tags: django, modelform

I am trying to create a reservation form that creates an object for model Reservation when the form is posted. I am using a custom datepicker widget to pick the ate, but I am also using ModelForms.

The issue is that, if I do not have 'date' listed in the meta fields list in the forms.py, then the form doesn't look for the date field form input on post. But if I include 'date' inside the meta fields of the forms.py Modelform, then it errors and says "date field can not be left blank" even though it is not blank...

**forms.py**

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    date = forms.DateField(
        widget=DatePickerInput(format='%m/%d/%Y')
        )
    def clean_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['date']

        # Check if a date is not in the past.
        if data < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - reservation in past'), code='invalid')
            messages.danger(request, "Reservation Created")
            print('ERROR')


            # Remember to always return the cleaned date.
            return data

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('reservation_time', 'people', 'name', 'email', 'phone') # REMOVED 'date'
```

**views.py**

```
def reservationFormView(request):
    #reservation = create(Reservation)
        # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)

        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required

            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.ReservationEmail = form.cleaned_data['email']
            reservation.ReservationName = form.cleaned_data['name']
            reservation.ReservationPeople = form.cleaned_data['people']
            reservation.ReservationTime = form.cleaned_data['reservation_time']
            reservation.date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            print( reservation.date)
            #reservation.created_time = timezone.now()
            reservation.save()

                # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/reservation-confirmation/')

        # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
    else:
        form = ReservationForm()

    return render(request, 'home/reservation_form.html', {'form': form, })
```

**models.py**

```
class Reservation(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Reservations"

    TIME_CHOICES = (
...
    )
    SEATING_CHOICES = (
...
    )
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)   #USE THIS https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    people = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SEATING_CHOICES, default=None, db_index=True)
    reservation_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_CHOICES, default=None, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s) %s %s' % (self.date, self.name, self.phone )
```

Comment: You wrote `return data` in the body of the `if` part, not at the end of the method.

Comment: Thank you for the input, you are correct, that solved the issue.

Comment: no the indentation is too much. If you look at the documentation you refer to, the `return ...` is indented under the `def clean_date`, not the `if`.

Comment: I edited the reply, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clean_date` method does *not* return a value in case the `if` condition is `False`. You should return the cleaned data in case it is correct, like:

```
def clean_date(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['date']

    # Check if a date is not in the past.
    if data < datetime.date.today():
        raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - reservation in past'), code='invalid')
        messages.danger(request, "Reservation Created")

    # not indented under the if
    return data
```

Otherwise, this function will return `None` in case the data is valid, and raise a `ValidationError` in case the data is invalid.